# Is it possible to print the sequence of the selected image in the dataset for the trained neural network?

Tags: keras, neural-network, dataset, tensorflow2.0, training-data

When training our dataset into a deep learning model such as CNN. I wanted to track the sequence of each image in the dataset that is selected for training each epoch in the neural network. Is it possible to print the sequence of the selected image?

I wanted to share my analysis as an example that if my dataset has only 10 images, the sequence of 10 images combination is factorial 10 = 3628800.
As an example,

**Sequence 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10**

**Sequence 2: 2,5,4,3,10,7,8,1,6**

**Sequence 3: 10,8,6,1,2,3,9,7,4,5**

**Sequence 4: 1,8,3,?,?,?,?,?,?,?**

**Sequence n: ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?**

The sequence is important for training the network. If the model is trained on sequence 1, the result is may different when I trained my network with sequence 2 or 3 or 4. The neural network weight and bias values are changed with the sequences.

I'm working with Keras and TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1):

Which framework are you using? In case it's ***PyTorch***, you can always pass `shuffle=False` to DataLoader and take array of image paths from custom *dataloader* module.

Example:

```
def __init__(self, transform=None):
    self.input_images = glob.glob('someimagedir')
    self.target_masks = [x.replace('image', 'mask') for x in self.input_images]        
    self.transform = transform

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.input_images)

def __getitem__(self, idx):        
    image = self.input_images[idx]
    mask = self.target_masks[idx]
    if self.transform:
        image = self.transform(image)
    
    return [image, mask]
```

Here, after you set `shuffle=False` in ***DataLoader***, the training process will always follow the same pattern as you'll see in `self.input_images` or `self.target_masks`